# Map Reduce split dataset into columns

Tags: java, python, csv, mapreduce, dataset

I have a TSV/CSV dataset( over 100gb) and I need to split the dataset into column datasets. An example : an input dataset of n rows and m cols need to output m datasets, each with one columns of n rows.

**Input 1 Dataset**

```
a  b  c
x  y  z
1  v  a
```

**Output 3 Datasets**

```
dataset1 : a x 1
dataset2 : b y v
dataset3 : c z a
```

Comment: your ouput will need to be in files, as 100Gb is quite hard to fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is to

- open the input file for reading
- read the first line using your favorite TSV/CSV parser
- that will give you `m`
- open `m` files for writing
- write the `i`th value of the line in the `i`th file
- read another line

An implementation example would be:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    files = [open("output" + str(i), 'w') for i in range(len(csvreader.next()))]
    f.seek(0)
    for line in csvreader:
        for i, value in enumerate(line):
            files[i].write(value)
            files[i].write(' ')
```